# Exact short sequence

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, exact-sequence

> Given a subspace $V_1$ of $V$, then
> $$
> \{0\} \xrightarrow{} V_1 \xrightarrow{i}  V \xrightarrow{\pi_{V/ V_1}}  V/V_1 
> \xrightarrow{} \{0\}
> $$
> is a exact short sequence.

> Q: Is this something that I have to prove? What exactly do I have to prove?

Comment: It looks like a pure statement and not an assignment/question.  If you don't understand why it is true, yes, you should prove it. It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Step 1: Look up the definition of a short exact sequence.
Step 2: Notice that there will be three things to check to prove it is a short exact sequence, and go ahead by proving these three things. They should be quite clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a sequence $A \overset{f}{\rightarrow} B \overset{g}{\rightarrow}C$, being exact *in B* means that $\operatorname{Ker}(g)=\operatorname{Im}(f)$. So you have to prove that your sequence is exact in $V_1$, $V$ and $V/V_1$, i.e. that the map $i$ is injective, the projection $\pi_{V/V_1}$ is surjective and that the image of the latter is equal to the kernel of the former. It is quite obvious but if you have any doubt, just prove it!

Comment: This is a huge help. Last point is, in order to prove that the sequence is exact in $V_1$ I have to know what is the map $\{0\}\to V_1$ and similarly for the other endpoint.

Comment: Yes, but there is only one map from and to the $\{0\}$ vector space...

Comment: Perfect! I got it, thank you very much.